# How to factor out common parameter in Enum?

Tags: java, enums

Here, Enum1, Enum2 and Enum3 share the `same` List. How to factor out this common code they share?

```
public enum EnumQ {

    Enum1 ("A", 1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")),
    Enum2 ("B", 1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")),
    Enum3 ("C", 1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"));

    private final String foo;
    private final int bar;
    private final List<String> list;

    private EnumQ(
        final String foo, final int bar, final List<String> list) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want an identical list in every instance of your enum? What is that getting you?

Comment: I have a specific use-case, unfortunately.

Comment: A specific use-case. Specifically ...?

Comment: You _could_ just remove the `list` from your constructor arguments and create it in your constructor. Or you could _not_ have an identical list in every instance of your enum. Without out knowing what you are trying to do, it is hard to advise.

Comment: Can't you do `this.list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")` instead of providing it from the outside?

Comment: By the way, enum having a mutable list as one of its fields, is a very bad idea...

Comment: What if it wasn't _all_ enums that shared the same list, but just some of them, while others had a different list? This question is still relevant.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yup there is no guarantee, all enums in future will share the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract it to constant. However, because it's an enum, you can't create a constant in `EnumQ`. This can be solved by using nested private class. Also, you should make this list immutable.

```
public enum EnumQ {

    Enum1("A", 1, Constants.STRINGS),
    Enum2("B", 1, Constants.STRINGS),
    Enum3("C", 1, Constants.STRINGS);

    private final String foo;
    private final int bar;
    private final List<String> list;

    EnumQ(String foo, int bar, List<String> list) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private static class Constants {
        private static final List<String> STRINGS = unmodifiableList(asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the list is always the same, It could be removed from the constructor parameter ;)

Comment: @azro True, but in the comment under the question OP wrote that in the future it might change. Although now that I think about it, I am actually with you - we should write the simplest code possible and refactor it only when requirements do change in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a nested enum.

```
public enum EnumQ {
    Enum1 ("A", 1, ListEnum.A_TO_K),
    Enum2 ("B", 1, ListEnum.A_TO_K),
    Enum3 ("C", 1, ListEnum.A_TO_K);

    private final String foo;
    private final int bar;
    private final ListEnum list;

    private EnumQ(
            final String foo, final int bar, final ListEnum list) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private enum ListEnum {
        A_TO_K(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"));
        private final List<String> list;

        private ListEnum(List<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes more sense when the data you move into the nested enum (here list) represent some standalone (reusable) entity/object.

Comment: A private nested enum? Nothing from outside this class will be able to access this list...

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It need not I believe. It is there to take out and group the repeated params of the outer enum